# When do engine type and mileage of a car affect pricing?

Tags: engine, fuel-consumption

I'm currently designing a customer relationship management tool for auto shop owners and was wondering:

1. Does engine type or the odometer value of a car ever affect pricing for a customer?
2. What considerations must be made to accommodate these differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The odometer reading is one of the key factors for pricing of a used car. The combination of mileage, age and physical condition of the car are enough to vary the price anywhere down to a tiny fraction of the list price.

The engine size, while important, it's more like the difference an alternative model may have. One engine size might be known as the best one (eg the 2.8 Ford Capri)

Have a look at some used car websites and do your own comparison based on mileage and you will see how significant it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would the odometer reading affect the price of service/repair for a car?

Comment: As an example, the 75k service on my car is an expensive one, with some major work scheduled by the manufacturer, but the 90k is just a cheap oils and consumables check.

Answer (score 4):

The engine type can definitely affect the price of a service job. Something like a timing belt service can be simple on one engine type and horrendous on another, due to things like accessibility of the components. A water pump could be directly accessible on one engine type, but require removal of the whole front bumper for access on another.